# Can I apply an update statement to multiple databases at the same time?

Tags: sql-server

Say I want to run the following:

```
update users set age = 10
```

on databases:

```
db1, db2, db3
```

All on the same server, I want to loop through and perform the same action.

Currently I am doing this manually using management studio via the dropdown.

Hoping there is a better way.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: This belongs on Database Administrators SE. (http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do it with dynamic SQL.  Something like so:

```
create table #dbs (db_name sysname not null)
insert into #dbs values ('db1'),('db2'),('db3')

declare curs cursor for
select db_name from #dbs
declare @db sysname, @sql nvarchar(max)
open curs

while(1=1)
begin
   fetch next from curs into @db
   if (@@fetch_status <> 0)
      break
   set @sql = 'update ' + quotename(@db) + '.dbo.users set age = 10'
   exec(@sql)
end
close curs
deallocate curs
drop table #dbs
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about doing it 'dynamically', i.e. a FOR-EACH style loop on all the databases in a server, but this should work:

```
USE db1
    update users set age = 10
GO
USE db2
   update users set age = 10
GO
USE db3
    update users set age = 10
```

Comment: hehe, well the idea was to have a loop somehow, this is repeating the script which I want to avoid for maintenance reasons, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Designate a server as a central management server and then add the other servers to the server group. Then you can run the update on all databases within the group. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934126.aspx

Comment: That will allow you to run a statement on multiple *servers*, but not multiple databases.

Comment: Multiple servers = multiple databases :) Granted the databases on each server need to be named the same, but if they are then this is the solution to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
use [WWAUTHxxx__]  -- a db containing active databases.
set nocount on
declare @Catalog as nvarchar(32)
declare @LibraryName as varchar(255)
declare @dbtable as varchar(50)
declare @retval as nvarchar(50)
declare @sSQL as nvarchar(max)
declare @parmdef as nvarchar(500)
declare @retvalout as nvarchar(50)
Declare Library_Cursor Cursor for
   select  top(1000)    xCatalog, xLibraryName
          from Active_DBs  
order by xcatalog
    Open Library_Cursor;
Fetch Next from Library_Cursor  into @Catalog, @LibraryName
   while @@Fetch_status = 0
       begin
         set @dbTable = @Catalog + '.dbo.las_circperiods' 
         set @ParmDef = N'@retvalOUT int OUTPUT';
         set @sSQL = N'Select @retvalout =  count(*) from ' + @dbtable
              + ' where xlastcircdate is null'
        exec sp_executesql @ssql,@parmdef,@retvalout=@retval output


     if @retval > 0  -- check/print Sql and then activate.
                     -- I like checking to see the potentially affected databases.
           begin 
              print @Catalog   + ',' +  @LibraryName + ',' + @retval 
              set @ssql = N'update ' + @dbTable 
                + ' set xlastcircdate = ''''  '
                + ' where xlastcircdate is null'

        --  print @ssql  -- View what you might will do
       exec sp_executesql @ssql    -- Do it.
            end

         Fetch Next from Library_Cursor  into @Catalog, @LibraryName
       end;
     close Library_cursor
     Deallocate Library_cursor
```

Comment: This is the best/safest way I have found to selectively update multiple data bases.